# WooCommerce Nodejs Response Error

Tags: php, node.js, wordpress, curl, woocommerce

I am trying to get a product detail from WordPress woo-commerce store. For that i am using [nodejs woo-commerce module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/woocommerce) 
But when i make a request i get the following error from server

```
{"status":"FAIL","message":"Invalid Signature - provided signature does not match"}
```

and  `401 Unauthorized`

But when i tried the same thing with php [WooCommerce-REST-API-Client-Library](https://github.com/kloon/WooCommerce-REST-API-Client-Library) which is using curl, i got the desired result.

I have searched different things, even compared the headers and url parameters etc, for both php and nodejs reqeust.
I have also tried this with nodejs curlrequest module.

Can anybody please guide me in the right direction.

I am passing the following options to node module:

```
{
  url:'my-woocommerce.com', 
  port:'81', 
  consumerKey:'ck_402b945d4b8a5017bb507df68295e833', 
  secret:'cs_5ac59207f8cb8c444ca4c4336ccc84e1'
}
```

Comment: I would double check the API URL in both cases (even going as far as running fiddler or similar tool and comparing the requests).

Comment: I have verified the api url again, and it looks fine.

Comment: I hope you also checked http vs https and www in front of the domain name vs the domain by itself. If they are the same in both API requests check if the URL you are using is the same as the URL defined in your WordPress general settings. Please also check if the consumer key and secret are the same and if the encodings of the both requests are the same.

Comment: Sample example here `http://my-woocommerce.dev:81/wc-api/v2/products/70?oauth_consumer_key=ck_402b945d4b8a5017bb507df68295e833&oauth_timestamp=1435655668&oauth_nonce=6b44a4896777c4264a84bdf17be1f5a174e9b559&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA256&oauth_signature=qte6vA9%2BZfgvIWd%2FflEq7ntvTcECrAoWrXyO6kGJptk%3D`

Comment: Is this a request that works? If so - can you also sent the options object that you passed to WooCommerce?

Comment: I'm assuming that the .com in the url is there by mistake right?

Comment: no the actual url is `http://woo2.piggybaq.com:81`, i gave the sample url in code.